# V1 to V2 PathPrefix

Tags: docker, traefik

Hello i migrate V1 to V2

i use this in v1 :

```
labels:
- "traefik.web.port=8082"
- "traefik.web.frontend.rule=Host:${pom_subdomain}._URL_SITE_"
- "traefik.wss.port=8081"
- "treafik.wss.frontend.entrypoints=ws"
- "traefik.wss.frontend.rule=Host:${pom_subdomain}._URL_SITE_;PathPrefixStrip:/rest"
- "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"
```

So i looking documentation : https://docs.traefik.io/migration/v1-to-v2/

so voila :

```
labels:
- "traefik.enable=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.aideopp.entrypoints=web"
- "traefik.http.routers.aideopp.rule=Host(\${pom_subdomain}.URL_SITE\)"
- "traefik.http.services.aideopp.loadbalancer.server.port=8082"
- "traefik.http.routers.aideopp-ws.entrypoints=web"
- "traefik.http.routers.aideopp-ws.rule=Host(`${pom_subdomain}.URL_SITE`) && PathPrefix(`/rest`)"
- "traefik.http.services.aideoperateur-ws.loadbalancer.server.port=8081"
- "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"
```

But its not worked :/ some body i have good eye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a StripPrefix for "/rest"?

Try:

- "traefik.http.middlewares.stripprefix-rest.stripprefix.prefixes=/rest"
- "traefik.http.routers.aideopp-ws.middlewares=stripprefix-rest@docker

This worked for me using Docker Swarm.